# Making SQL Server Management Studio use SQL Server 2016 instead of 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms-2012, ssms-2016

I was recently using SQL Server 2012 which was connected properly with my SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio). Then I downloaded SQL Server 2016 yesterday and installed it.

Problem is, when I run SSMS, it opens up SQL Server 2012 instead of 2016. How can I make SSMS point to SQL Server 2016?

Thank you!

Comment: have you tried choosing the correct server when connecting ?

Comment: are you saying,new connection manager by default points out to 2012 instance?

Comment: Run `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe"` and/or pin that to your menu/taskbar rather than the existing one. if you don't have it, [download it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt238290).

Comment: when opening SMSS you can define in which Server instance your are connecting to.

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about the version of SSMS you want to use or the default instance?

One is a question that involves changing your windows shortcut, the other probably requires you to lookup the instance name in the SQL Server Configuration tool and using this when you connect

2012: 
     `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe"`

2016: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe"`

config manager
2016: `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mmc.exe /32 C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager13.msc`